# How do i prove programatically if a String was initialized?

Tags: java, string

Though the logging level is set to INFO, and that at runtime the condition will never be satisfied, how am i able to prove programatically if "`Hi`" will not be initialized?

```
if(log.isDebug()){
    log.debug("Hi");
}
```

What i mean is, since the logging level is INFO, the logger would not have a chance to print the message "Hi", my concern is, how can i find out if the JRE or JDK will / will not take a step to prepare "Hi" even through the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: Do you mean `s == null`?

Comment: I think his question is, Hi will never executed because of log level, but how can he prove it?

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking. The String literal "Hi" is initialized by the class loader when the class is loaded because it is a literal. Are you asking if you can prove whether or not it is _logged_?

Comment: Hi Ted, does it mean that irregardless of whether the logging level is correct, the String literal "Hi" is initialized by the class loaded when the class is loaded? And this String literal is possible in the String interned pool?

Comment: The String "Hi" is ***not*** created unless referenced by executing code, at least not in any reasonable version of a JVM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dump the bytecodes.  There will be an "ldc" opcode for the String constant.  The first time that opcode is executed is when the actual String will be created.  The String will then be cached in the constant pool for reuse on subsequent calls/iterations.  If the "ldc" never executes the String is not created.

Comment: Hi Hot Licks, i read your other comments, can you please expand on the part where you mentioned "Actually, the String value will generally not be created unless referenced. There will be a "load constant" opcode in the bytecodes, and the first time that executes the constant is extracted from the constant pool and a String object created. "

Comment: Each class has a constant pool.  Part of the pool is an invariant structure taken from the .class file, but part is a table that can be dynamically updated.  When a constant String is referenced, the table is checked (ie, is the pointer null?) to see if the constant has been created yet.  If not, the UTF8 value from the invariant structure is expanded into UTF16 and used to create (and intern) a String.  The String's pointer is then stored in the table.  (At least this is the way it works in the canonical JVM, absent any special treatment of the class.)

Answer (score 3):

The literal String "Hi" is part of the class definition. Unless the *compiler* can determine that the body of the `if` is dead code and the literal is not needed, then when the class loader loads the class it will load the literal value. Since it is a compile-time constant, it will also be automatically interned.

The compiler cannot know what the behavior of `log.isDebug()` will be when the class is loaded into some unknown execution environment. For all it knows, the logger class definition may be changed so that `isDebug()` returns `true` regardless of the value set for the logging level.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing needing to be "initialized" in this code; the string literal "Hi" will be placed into your `.class` file by the compiler, so it'll be available for use at runtime regardless of whether it's ever actually used.

Comment: Actually, the String value will generally not be created unless referenced.  There will be a "load constant" opcode in the bytecodes, and the first time that executes the constant is extracted from the constant pool and a String object created.

Comment: So the string will be present in the bytecode, but not loaded into memory if its value is never used at runtime.  I guess you could call that "not initialized".

Answer (score 0):

I think of the string literal "Hi" is initialised in heap memory readonly

you can do a method like this and calculate memory delta :

```
    if(log.isDebug()){
     log.debug("literal");

     log.debug(memoryUsed());
        log.debug("Hi");
     log.debug(memoryUsed());

     log.debug("initialising");

     log.debug(memoryUsed());
     string x = "Hi"
     log.debug(x);
     log.debug(memoryUsed());
    }


    static long memoryUsed()
      {
      return runtime.totalMemory () - runtime.freeMemory ();
      }
```

Comment: All Strings are "readonly", in that they are immutable.  There is nothing special about "Hi", once created, other than strings from the constant pool are always interned, while interning requires user action for user-created strings.